# Como convertir un ComboBox de String a Int?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito converitir un ComboBox al cual llame `cmbmes`. La realidad es que no me funciona con `Convert.ToInt32()` ni con `Int.Parse()`. El error que me da en especifico es `System.FormatException`.

Lo que quiero lograr es que al seleccionar un Item (Numero) del ComboBox me diga en un TextBox el Mes.

El codigo es este:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Numero de Meses del Año
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            cmbmes.Items.Add(i);
        }

        //Para seleccionar el Mes
        int numero;                       
        numero = int.Parse(cmbmes.Text);

        if (numero == 1)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Enero";
        }
        else if (numero == 2)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Febrero";
        }

    }
```

Si conocen otro metodo, se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Esto es winforms? wpf? mas alla de eso, porque queres convertir un numero de mes en el texto, cuando al usuario deberias mostrarle el texto y tener los value como numeros?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pesar de que parece que lo has resuelto, voy a añadir una respuesta por si alguien se encuentra en la misma situación y no quiere reinventar la rueda. En .net existe el método [`GetMonthName(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx) que te devuelve el nombre del mes pasándole un entero con el numero de mes. En tu caso el código se reduciría a:

```
//Hay que añadir este using
using System.Globalization;
...
private void cmbmes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtmes.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(int.Parse(cmbmes.Text));
}
```

Si necesitas que la primera letra del mes esté en mayúsculas, simplemente añade debajo de `txtmes.text = ...` esta línea:

```
txtmes.Text = txtmes.Text.First().ToString().ToUpper() + txtmes.Text.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Solo como nota, vale muchisimo mas cargar el combo con los valores y los textos correspondientes y no hacer todos estos malabares despues.

Comment: Joder. Si que eres bueno

Answer (score 0):

```
int numero;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Numero de Meses del Año
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            cmbmes.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

private void cmbmes_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Para seleccionar el Mes                      
        numero = Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text);

        if (numero == 1)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Enero";
        }
        else if (numero == 2)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Febrero";
        }
}
```

Prueba con esto... tengo rato que no toco `c#` pero es algo así.. te explico un poco el código

En el evento load del `form` añadimos los `items` a tu `combobox`

Y luego en el evento [SelectionChangeCommitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx) de tu `combobox` recogemos el numero que hemos seleccionado de este, y  ya solo comparamos y desplegamos en tu `textbox` el mes dependiendo del número...

Answer (score -1):

pero al fin logre encontrar la respuesta sin error.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Numero de Meses del Año
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            cmbmes.Items.Add(i);
        }
    }

    private void txtmes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
    }

    private void cmbmes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text)==1)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Enero";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 2)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Febrero";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 3)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Marzo";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 4)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Abril";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 5)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Mayo";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 6)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Junio";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 7)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Julio";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 8)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Agosto";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 9)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Septiembre";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 10)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Octubre";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 11)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Noviembre";
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(cmbmes.Text) == 12)
        {
            txtmes.Text = "Diciembre";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Menuda cadena de `if` esa... Todo eso puede ser resumido a 3 lineas de código, como minimo...

Comment: Aunque todo esto es muy lindo, y la solucion de pikoh es muchisimo mejor que esta, un combo puede tener toda esta informacion de antemano sin necesidad de todo esto!